# Customizing an Editable Grid widget: changing the behavior of a section of an editable grid from BonitaSOFT

Tags: service, soa, bpmn, bonita

I am working on Bonita Open source version of 6.4.2 for my project of end of study and I'm facing a big problem to which I'm not finding any coming.
In fact I have a form with an editable Grid widget in which the user enter some data which will be transported to a DB MySQL, at this stage everything works perfectly.

Besides a new constraint occurred to me: I must populate the boxes of the first column with a list of values from my database so that when a user clicks on this boxes the list scrolls and the value will be picked from this list (the same behavior as the Select widget) but inside a table.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this cannot be achieved with the Editable Grid widget that is provided out of the box (it only allows basic text input).

To implement the kind of UI you described, you have two possible solutions:

- Use Bonita BPM Subscription edition's **dynamic form** feature. This will allow you to create repeatable groups of widgets representing rows of your table. This solution allows to use any types of widgets with data and validators.
- Create a HTML widget that contains a **JavaScript UI component** inside it such as [DataTables](http://www.datatables.net). This solution is quite flexible but it requires some good/advanced JS coding skills in order to integrate the custom table, link it with the form data and implement validators.

Cheers,

POZ